# Appium driver NOT suggesting removeapp() function inside the code base

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I want to user driver.removeapp({bundleID}); command in my appium script BUT IDE NOT suggesting this method even I've imported io.appium.java_client.*;

[image: Imports]

[image: code base]

Comment: `removeApp(..)` method is declared in the `InteractsWithApps` interface. Could you please show your `driver` declaration?

Comment: @YevhenDanchenko Thanks so much. Issue was in the driver declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double check the declaration of your driver variable:

```
    public AppiumDriver driver;

    driver = new IOSDriver(appiumURL, capabilities);

    driver.removeApp(bundleId);
```